# Combine two queries into 1 (without requiring tmp table creation)

Tags: sql

I populated a table by creating two queries.  The first one pulls a distinct combination of 2 columns out into a temp table.  The second one does a left join on the temp table with another.  Here are the queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID  
INTO #tmpID
FROM Staging.Name

SELECT * 
FROM Perf.Hours w
LEFT JOIN #tmpID wr ON w.Name = wr.Name
```

I want to create one query that will allow me to confirm the counts of the Perf.Hours table is correct.  When I run the above 2 queries separately, the count in Staging.Name matches the count on the Perf.Hours table.  I am struggling to create one query without having to create a tmp table.  Any ideas?

Here is my latest attempt:

```
SELECT count(*) 
    from (
SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID  
FROM Staging.Name
LEFT JOIN Perf.Hours wr ON w.Name = wr.Name
) AS Staging
```

But the count is not matching at all.

Comment: SELECT count(*) from (SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID FROM staging.Name) A LEFT JOIN Perf.Hours wr ON wr.Name = A.Name) AS Staging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the first one as a "Table Expression". For example:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Perf.Hours w
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID  
  FROM Staging.Name
) wr ON w.Name = wr.Name
```

You can also combine them treating the first one as a CTE (Common Table Expression), as in:

```
with
wr as (
  SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID  
  FROM Staging.Name
)
SELECT count(*)
FROM Perf.Hours w
LEFT JOIN wr ON w.Name = wr.Name
```

Comment: Thank you!  Both of them teach me something new with SQL to boot